# When does $f$ identically zero

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in\mathcal C[-\pi,\pi]$ satisfying $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x^nf(x)dx=0~\forall~n\in\mathbb Z^+.$ Does $f=0?$

Comment: The answer is yes, so try for a proof. Of course, as julien says, you have to use the Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Try to approximate $ \overline{f} $ using polynomial functions on $ [- \pi,\pi] $, which is possible via the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. After having done this, what can you then say about $ \displaystyle \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} |f|^{2} ~ d{x} $?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).